# Unable to fetch any items from MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My connection with the mongodb server gets established but I am unable to fetch any items from there.
This is a simple query to get all items from the User collection.

```
User.find({}, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
    });
```

My `User` schema is very simple as well:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 35,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 100,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 20,
  },
});

module.exports = {
  User: mongoose.model("user", userSchema),
};
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling mistake on my end. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Is the User.find() call inside of a route? If not, res.json() will not work. Try console.log ing it.

Comment: aah, sorry to bother but there was a silly spelling mistake on my side, due to which I couldn't resolve it. It works fine now!